# R/ ggplot2/ how to move from connected points in a scatter plot to filled and transparent triangles?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry

Here are the x and y coordinates from a  multidimensional scaling 
experiment: three cases with different distance metrics and 
scaling/ no scaling. "Set" is the metrics-scaling combination
(1 to 6). Each case has a class label (0 or 4).

```
       X1         X2     method       scale class set
1   18.881729  -2.931111 euclidean     no     0   1
2  -13.141592  -9.750710 euclidean     no     4   1
3   -5.740138  12.681822 euclidean     no     4   1
4  -21.886160 -15.467637 manhattan scaled     0   2
5  -16.755615  16.900148 manhattan scaled     4   2
6   38.641776  -1.432512 manhattan scaled     4   2
7   32.927820  -7.900971 minkowski     no     0   3
8  -28.957697 -11.666982 minkowski     no     4   3
9   -3.970123  19.567953 minkowski     no     4   3
10   5.944225  25.819482 euclidean scaled     0   4
11  44.574669 -15.330675 euclidean scaled     4   4
12 -50.518894 -10.488807 euclidean scaled     4   4
13  14.287762   1.142065 manhattan     no     0   5
14  -5.843410  -9.981600 manhattan     no     4   5
15  -8.444351   8.839535 manhattan     no     4   5
16 -24.838956  -8.194378 minkowski scaled     0   6
17 -11.435517  10.496471 minkowski scaled     4   6
18  36.274473  -2.302093 minkowski scaled     4   6
```

and ggplotting:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(scale), shape = factor(method)), size=10)
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label=class), size=5)
p <- p + geom_line(aes(X1,X2, group=factor(set)))
p <- p + theme_bw()
p
```

[image]

I would like to make 6 filled and transparent triangles one for each group ("set").
The top triangle being Manhattan-No scaling. My experiments with geom_segment have
not been successful and I am not sure whether geom_polygon is the right direction.
Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `geom_polygon` for closed paths:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2))
p <- p + geom_polygon(aes(fill = factor(set)), alpha = .4)
p <- p + theme_bw()
p
```

Here, `alpha` is used to specify the degree of transparency.

[image]